# How can we manage non-code files in TFS for designers, etc?

Tags: version-control, tfs

Normally projects consist of a set of non-source code files like interface images (PSDs, JPGs,...). How can we managing these types of files with TFS and how graphic designers can check-in or out their image files to use them in applications like Photoshop?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add binary files (PSD, JPG etc.) to your tree, with the following caveats:

- Large files take more space on the server. A quote from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/6f642d0f-5459-4a14-a19d-ede34713bcf4 :
  TFS does handle large (> 16mb) files differently.  It does not perform Delta storage but instead stores a complete copy of each version.  This is an optimization to make check-ins faster for those large files.  There is no difference between text files and binary files.  Small ones are Delta'd, large ones are Stored.
- Large files take slower to download (see the same link above).
- If there is a conflict (i.e. two people modify the same binary file at the same time), one of them has to resolve the conflict completely manually, e.g. he has to load all 3 image versions in the image editor, look at the differences, and merge the changes manually.

Comment: What about the team build? Does it copies them to the build location or it is configurable?